# LiveStreet как удалить пользователя

Tags: php, livestreet

В движке не предусмотрена модерация, бан, или удаление пользователя.

Как тогда можно удалить или забанить хулиганов?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню LS, в нем вообще админка не предусмотрена из коробки, поэтому путей решения этой проблемы несколько:

- Использовать платные сторонние плагины, в каталоге на сайте их полно;
- Писать свои плагины для этих целей;
- Делать это напрямую, через запрос к БД. Я бы советовал не удалять пользователей и посты с комментариями, чтобы проблем не получить, а отключать, как-то так:

  UPDATE `prefix_user` SET `user_activate`=0 WHERE `user_id`=ID;

  UPDATE `prefix_topic` SET `topic_publish`=0 WHERE `user_id`=ID;

  UPDATE `prefix_comment` SET `comment_delete`=1 WHERE `user_id`=ID;